# Reversibility of Voltera Integral Equations and Ordinary Differential Equations Conversions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I transformed the IVP below into a Volterra Integral Equation:

$$y''+2xy'+y=0$$
$$y(0)=1, y'(0)=0$$

And I got this:

$$u(x)=-1-\int_0^x(3x-t)u(t)dt$$

Now out of curiosity, I ventured converting the Volterra Integral Equation back to an IVP using the method described in the Textbook: A First Course in Integral Equations by Abdul-Majid Wazwaz and I got an entirely different IVP.

Here was my step:

$$u(x)=-1-\int_0^x(3x-t)u(t)dt$$

Differentiating wrt x gives:

$$u'(x)=-\int_0^x3u(t)dt$$

Differentiating further:

$$u''(x)=-3u(x) $$

Fixing $u(x) = y$

$$y''+3y=0$$

The initial conditions are:

$$y(0)=0, y'(0)=1$$

So you can see that I didn't end up getting the initial IVP I started with.

So, my question is: Are the conversion between Volterra Integral Equations and ODEs reversible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written is not quite right. Observe
\begin{align}
 \frac{d}{dx}\int^x_0 (3x-t)u(t)\ dt  = 2xu(x) + 3\int^x_0 u(t)\ dt.
\end{align}

Comment: Oh, that's true! I got my differentiation all wrong. I forgot to use the Liebniz rule strictly.

Comment: A quick one: can this equation be regarded as a volterra equation: $u(x)=\sin x - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^x(x-t)^2dt$

Comment: @Obinoscopy I don't know. I have to think a bit about this.

Comment: Okay. My confusion is  actually the absence of the unknown function $u(t) $ inside the integral